# Drupal panel / view not showing in print view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I have a Drupal 5 site that is using the Printer, e-mail and PDF versions module that appears to be creating a print version of a URL like so:

screen:
country/uk

print: 
print/country/uk

Each page is set up using panels and has the country image and a view of most recent country news below.

On the print/country/xxx the view isn't present.  Any ideas on what could be causing that?

I'm new to Drupal 5 as well as panels/context. The solution may be something as simple as a checkbox setting or more complicated, but I have no leads so far on where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to go to the settings and enable the 'show link for non-content pages' to cover that page. http://drupal.org/node/294209

I haven't tried it out myself, but if you get stuck I can install on a drupal 5 install and try it out.

Good luck!